# conjure-up cannot create user data directory

Tags: snap, conjure-up, kubernetes

I have a new installation of Ubuntu 16.04 Server 64-bit. I am trying to setup a basic kubernetes environment using conjure-up.

First of all, I have installed conjure-up via snap as instructed on the Ubuntu documentation: https://docs.ubuntu.com/conjure-up/en/:

```
sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
```

It seems to go fine with the following message:

```
2017-08-07T07:53:04+03:00 INFO cannot auto connect core:core-support-plug to core:core-support: (slot auto-connection), existing connection state "core:core-support-plug core:core-support" in the way
conjure-up 2.2.2 from 'canonical' installed
```

Next, I run conjure-up kubernetes or even conjure-up without any params, it always fails and produces the following message:

```
cannot create user data directory: /home/local/DOMAIN/user/snap/conjure-up/549: Permission denied
```

I checked that folder and I could write into it without any problem, so I don't understand really what's going on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the log message, it seems that your `$HOME` is mounted on a network filesystem, like NFS or CIFS.

Currently there is a known limitation with snapd, that does not allow operation in such environment.

See also [Snaps with classic confinement and NFS /home](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snaps-with-classic-confinement-and-nfs-home/1706).

Comment: I have this error and my home is on a different partition using a symbolic link.  Is there a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error while attempting to `conjure-up kubernetes` on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  I was able to solve this by creating a file in `/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home.d` with the contents `@{HOMEDIRS}+=/home/DOMAIN/` (In your case it would be `@{HOMEDIRS}+=/home/local/DOMAIN/`).

You'll have to `sudo systemctl restart apparmor.service` or reboot for the changes to take effect.